# Jwt Token not provide current user details

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, jwt

I have created a demo application in .net core 2.0 with https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/ This is an example for Authentication with JWT Token, but I noticed that when I create a token for one user and replace it with another token created for another user (from other browser), it will validate and allow access. Why? 
Also if anyone has a good example of JWT token with current user logged in then please share the link, as I am new to this.

Comment: What do you mean with "JWT token with current user logged in" example?

Comment: i mean on www.xyz.com i am login with my system and you login from your, then we exchange our token and pass that to site then my login convert to you and your with me. so i want to stop this, so have you any idea or approach to handle this then please give guideline to me. thank you

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the Bearer authentication schema works.

> The server's protected routes will check for a valid JWT in the Authorization header, and if it's present, the user will be allowed to access protected resources.

(from :[How do JSON Web Tokens work?](https://jwt.io/introduction/))

So everyone who can present a valid and not expired token will get access to your protected resources. There's usually no check if the token was originally issued to you or to someone else.

You are of course free to implement such a check:

- find something that can't be forged to identify the device and is present on every request
- add this information or better a hashed value as a claim to the token. You're free to add [claims](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.3) (basically just key/value pairs) to your token.
- write your own custom authorization attribute and check if the request comes from the same device as stated in the respective claim in the JWT.

Comment: Thank you for reply, ok i got it that valid token will allow, but can we handle this using passing a value in body and validate token with that body value and check that weather this token is issue for this machine or other?

Comment: You seem to be very concerned about that. Is it a realistic scenario which you have to be worried about?

Comment: yes, i am currently facing this and getting this issue from my client. so need to fix this. thank you for support